# Selenium Grid Support - launch multiple browser windows from same machine

Tags: selenium, automation

We know that Selenium Grid is supporting parallel testing from different machines.

My Objective is to launch multiple browser windows from same machine and launch tests from same machine parallel. Is it possible with Selenium grid? Could you guide me here, please?

Regards,
-kranti

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: what has stopped u from trying this at your end first?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it and you can even specify how many windows you want to run at once on given computer. All is done through `-browser` parameter:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.42.0.jar -role node -browser browserName=firefox,maxInstances=3 -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
```

The above parameter allows the node to run up to 3 instances of firefox browser at once.

Later on, the computer will open 3 different instances of Firefox and run the tests. It worked well in my setup.